# Saltstack: deploy EC2 instances in several availability zones

Tags: saltstack

Just started learning Saltstack to control the infrastructure at AWS. We are developing an application to which time is really important, so we need to deploy from the beginning, a distributed infrastructure in order to achieve low traveling times.

I started to look at Salt because it is simple and effective. But now i need to deploy the instances and I don't understand some of the procedures.

Salt requires that you define the providers. In the provider you can specify the region and availability zone.
The problem: If you need to deploy in several regions and availability zones, it soon gets messy and too long.

The question? There's any way to automate this, without having to hardcode dozens of availability zones ?

Comment: Suggest you contact Saltstack for support with their product.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the availability zones in your profile. That way you can have a profile for each availability zone that you want.